# Hide columns except one based on Combobox value

Tags: excel, vba, filter

Looking for a little assistance with a code I'm attempting to right.

The Result should be that when a user clicks a button on a userform named "Btn_LaSearch" that all columns in a range E6:MB6 are hidden except for the column where the name in the range matches that in a combobox on the userform.

the code i have so far looks like this...

```
Private Sub Btn_LASearch_Click()

    Range("A1").Select
    
    ActiveCell.Value = Cbo_LocalList.Value
    
    Dim rngFound As Range
    Dim Target As String
    
    
    If Target.Address(0, 0) = "A1" Then

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        
        With Range("E6:MB6")
            .EntireColumn.Hidden = False 
            If Target <> "" Then
               Set rngFound = .Cells.Find(Target, , , xlWhole, , xlNext, False) 
               
               If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
                    .EntireColumn.Hidden = True 
                    rngFound.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 
                End If
          End If
        End With
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   End If
       
End Sub
```

I keep getting a *Compile Error: Invalid Qualifier* and it highlights this row.

**If Target.Address(0, 0) = "A1" Then**

I'm still very much an amateur when it comes to VBA so all help is appreciated.

Kind Regards,

Comment: Try changing `Target.Address(0,0)` to `Target.Address`.

Comment: Hi CLR, Just tried that and unfortunately it hasn't worked.

Comment: You still get the same error? Or now the issue is further along in your code?

Comment: Probably cause you can't get an address from a String.

Comment: Wow, yes Simon, I hadn't noticed this wasn't an event and Target is declared a string. Tomas, what are you attempting with the Target.Address test?

Comment: So currently. The Name that needs to be shown (and every other column in the range hidden) is pasted into cell A1. if I'm honest I've attempted to dissect a code found online and adapt it to my needs, but that was a private worksheet code but i need to operate it from a userform. so not sure if its even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're pasting the name into A1, then using that on a search when you already have access to the name.

Try something like this:

```
Private Sub Btn_LASearch_Click()

    Dim c as Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     
    For Each c In Range("E6:MB6")
        c.EntireColumn.Hidden = Not (c.Value = Cbo_LocalList.Value)
    Next
           
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: No problem Tomas. Are you happy you understand how this works?

Comment: am i right in saying that its looping through all the cells in the range looking for the combobox value, if it doesnt find it then it hides the collumn?

Comment: Yes, that's the gist of it. The bulk of the work is done by the Boolean test `(c.Value = Cbo_LocalList.Value)` which will result in a True or False if the strings match. So the `.Hidden` property of each column is set to `Not` (or the opposite of) the result of that test.